# How to tell if my program is being piped to another (Perl)

Tags: perl

"ls" behaves differently when its output is being piped:

```
 
> ls ??? 
bar  foo 
> ls ??? | cat 
bar 
foo
```

How does it know, and how would I do this in Perl?

Comment: This seems like a perfectly fine question to me.

Comment: This is slightly different from the other question: it asks about pipes specifically, not ttys, though I agree there is quite a bit of overlap.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Perl, the `-t` file test operator indicates whether a filehandle
(including `STDIN`) is connected to a terminal.

There is also the `-p` test operator to indicate whether a filehandle
is attached to a pipe.

```
$ perl -e 'printf "term:%d, pipe:%d\n", -t STDIN, -p STDIN'
term:1, pipe:0
$ perl -e 'printf "term:%d, pipe:%d\n", -t STDIN, -p STDIN' < /tmp/foo
term:0, pipe:0
$ echo foo | perl -e 'printf "term:%d, pipe:%d\n", -t STDIN, -p STDIN'
term:0, pipe:1
```

File test operator documentation at [`perldoc -f -X`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#X).

Comment: VERY nice! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
use IO::Interactive qw(is_interactive);

is_interactive() or warn "Being piped\n";
```